# GNU Make: always build pre-targets but don't rebuild target

Tags: gnu-make

Imagine my Makefile has something like:

```
CXXFLAGS = -O3 ${INCLUDES} --std=c++17 -g ${AUTO_ARGUMENT}
COMPILE.cc = $(CXX) $(DEPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c

.PHONY: all directories

all: directories programs

directories: obj

obj:
    mkdir obj

programs: Foo

Foo: obj/Foo.o
    ${CXX} obj/Foo.o ${LDFLAGS} -o Foo

obj/%.o : %.cpp
    $(COMPILE.cc) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<

clean:
    rm -rf Foo obj
```

I can execute `make` and it will create the obj subdirectory then do a nice compile and link. Works great. But if I do `make clean Foo`, it's going to fail. The clean removed the subdir and because I bypassed `all` to just make a single target, it doesn't recreate `obj`.

So I can do this:

```
Foo: directories obj/Foo.o
    ${CXX} obj/Foo.o ${LDFLAGS} -o Foo
```

But then it ALWAYS does the link:

```
$ make
g++ obj/Foo.o  -o Foo
$ make
g++ obj/Foo.o  -o Foo
```

But if I remove the `directories` part from Foo:

```
$ make
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

This is even worse:

```
obj/%.o : directories %.cpp
    $(COMPILE.cc) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
```

So, my question... Is there some way that I can tell an individual target to do some of the pre-setup without that target then always being rebuilt? I could probably make fake targets like this:

```
makeFoo: directories Foo
```

But that's annoying. I could also have all be:

```
all: setup programs

setup: directories
```

And then do `make setup Foo`. That's only moderately annoying. What I'd really like is the rule for the objects to ensure the directory exists without adding any spam or unnecessary rebuilds. I suppose I could add something to that particular rule to ensure the directory exists:

```
obj/Foo.o: Foo.cpp
   if [ -d obj ]; then \
      mkdir obj \
   fi
   $(COMPILE.cc) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
```

Is there a cleaner way?

Comment: `make clean Foo` is not supposed to work in its conventional meaning. Whether other targets can be passed together on command line can be thought of as part of the interface to the makefile in question. In other words the clean way is to say "don't", possibly with input validation (target count <= 1).

Comment: As for directories, have you looked into order-only dependencies? They are triggered on existence only, not timestamp, making the ideal for directories.

Comment: @Andreas I don't really understand what you're saying. I've been doing `make clean all` for 40 years.

Comment: @Andreas As for order-only dependencies -- that was EXACTLY what I needed. I've never used them before. Our industry has gotten so vast. I'm going to stick in an answer for anyone else looking to do the same thing.

Comment: I was thinking of parallelism, `make -j clean all`, in which case making and removing files would get interleaved. Plain `make clean all` works fine, making the targets left to right.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Andreas, I made some adjustments. Here's my entire sample Makefile:

```
CXXFLAGS = -O3 ${INCLUDES} --std=c++17 -g ${AUTO_ARGUMENT}
COMPILE.cc = $(CXX) $(DEPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c

.PHONY: all directories

all: directories programs

directories: | obj

obj:
    mkdir obj

programs: Foo

Foo: obj/Foo.o
    ${CXX} obj/Foo.o ${LDFLAGS} -o Foo

obj/%.o : %.cpp | obj
    $(COMPILE.cc) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<

clean:
    rm -rf obj Foo
```

And here are my runs:

```
$ make clean Foo
rm -rf obj Foo
mkdir obj
g++  -O3  --std=c++17 -g    -c -o obj/Foo.o Foo.cpp
g++ obj/Foo.o  -o Foo
$ make Foo
make: 'Foo' is up to date.
```

The trick was order-only dependencies -- the pipe thing. See the rule for `obj/%.o` and `directories`. Note that it works the same if I do it this way or if my `obj/%.o` rule used `directories` instead.